# Trouble with variable from Scanner

Tags: java

Can someone explain me why "pyt11" take "yes" If I type it manually but if I take it from Scanner and put String "a" that doesn't see my variable.

From pyt11(a) (If I type "yes" in Scanner) gives me b value 0.

From pyt11("yes")   gives me b value 20.

Someone knows why ?

```
public static Scanner into;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    into = new Scanner(System.in);
    String a = into.nextLine();
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(pyt11(a));
    System.out.println(pyt11("yes"));
}
static int pyt11(String odp11) 
{

    int b = 0;
    if (odp11 == "yes")
    {
        b = 20;
    }
    else if (odp11 == "maybe" || odp11 == "partially")
    {
        b = 10;
    }
    else if (odp11 == "no")
    {
        b = 0;
    }
    return b;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
if (odp11.equals("yes"))
```

when you compare String, becuase `==` test a reference equality insted of value.